# DropEvent does not work when dragging and dropping between widgets

Tags: pyqt5

I'm trying to get the behavior that when I drag and drop a `MyButton`, the dropEvent will be triggered in any part of the interface. Right now it works pretty much as needed, except for one thing. The dropEvent doesn't work if the mouse button is released between widgets, and I don't know how to fix this problem. For me it is very important that the dropEvent is always triggered, at the moment when the drag is finished, because at that moment I send a message to the server about the move made, and if at that moment the mouse was between the widgets, this message is not sent.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'DS_Test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDragEnterEvent, QDropEvent


class MyButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        btn_img = self.grab()
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(btn_img)
        painter.setCompositionMode(painter.CompositionMode_DestinationIn)
        painter.fillRect(btn_img.rect(), QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 150))
        painter.end()

        data = QtCore.QMimeData()
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(data)
        drag.setPixmap(btn_img)

        drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())
        self._pos = event.pos()

        drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
        super(MyButton, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)


class MyFrame(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e: QDragEnterEvent):
        e.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e: QDropEvent):
        self.parent().dropEvent(e)


class MyQDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dropEvent(self, e: QDropEvent):
        print("dropEvent - is done")
        e.accept()

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(1051, 800)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalFrame = MyFrame(Dialog)
        self.horizontalFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 211), stop:0.166 rgba(255, 255, 0, 211), stop:0.333 rgba(0, 255, 0, 211), stop:0.5 rgba(0, 255, 255, 211), stop:0.666 rgba(0, 0, 255, 211), stop:0.833 rgba(255, 0, 255, 211), stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 0, 211));")
        self.horizontalFrame.setObjectName("horizontalFrame")
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalFrame)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.pushButton_3 = MyButton(self.horizontalFrame)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = MyButton(self.horizontalFrame)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton = MyButton(self.horizontalFrame)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalFrame)
        self.horizontalFrame_2 = MyFrame(Dialog)
        self.horizontalFrame_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(9, 41, 4, 255), stop:0.085 rgba(2, 79, 0, 255), stop:0.19 rgba(50, 147, 22, 255), stop:0.275 rgba(236, 191, 49, 255), stop:0.39 rgba(243, 61, 34, 255), stop:0.555 rgba(135, 81, 60, 255), stop:0.667 rgba(121, 75, 255, 255), stop:0.825 rgba(164, 255, 244, 255), stop:0.885 rgba(104, 222, 71, 255), stop:1 rgba(93, 128, 0, 255));")
        self.horizontalFrame_2.setObjectName("horizontalFrame_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalFrame_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalFrame_2)
        self.horizontalFrame_3 = MyFrame(Dialog)
        self.horizontalFrame_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:0, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), stop:0.05 rgba(14, 8, 73, 255), stop:0.36 rgba(28, 17, 145, 255), stop:0.6 rgba(126, 14, 81, 255), stop:0.75 rgba(234, 11, 11, 255), stop:0.79 rgba(244, 70, 5, 255), stop:0.86 rgba(255, 136, 0, 255), stop:0.935 rgba(239, 236, 55, 255));")
        self.horizontalFrame_3.setObjectName("horizontalFrame_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalFrame_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_8")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalFrame_3)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = MyQDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Just implement `dragEnterEvent` and `dragMoveEvent` in the dialog. Also, don't call a parent's event handler from its child: if you want to allow dropping on a parent, just implement the drag and drop event handlers in the parent, not the child.ù

Answer (score 0):

As recommended in the comment, I added `dragEnterEvent` and `dragMoveEvent` to `MyQDialog`. Now everything works the way I want it to. Here is the corrected code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'DS_Test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDragEnterEvent, QDropEvent


class MyButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        btn_img = self.grab()
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(btn_img)
        painter.setCompositionMode(painter.CompositionMode_DestinationIn)
        painter.fillRect(btn_img.rect(), QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 150))
        painter.end()

        data = QtCore.QMimeData()
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(data)
        drag.setPixmap(btn_img)

        drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())
        self._pos = event.pos()

        drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
        super(MyButton, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)


class MyFrame(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e: QDragEnterEvent):
        e.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e: QDropEvent):
        self.parent().dropEvent(e)


class MyQDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e: QDragEnterEvent):
        e.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e: QDropEvent):
        print("dropEvent - is done")
        e.accept()

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(1051, 800)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalFrame = MyFrame(Dialog)
        self.horizontalFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 211), stop:0.166 rgba(255, 255, 0, 211), stop:0.333 rgba(0, 255, 0, 211), stop:0.5 rgba(0, 255, 255, 211), stop:0.666 rgba(0, 0, 255, 211), stop:0.833 rgba(255, 0, 255, 211), stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 0, 211));")
        self.horizontalFrame.setObjectName("horizontalFrame")
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalFrame)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.pushButton_3 = MyButton(self.horizontalFrame)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = MyButton(self.horizontalFrame)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton = MyButton(self.horizontalFrame)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalFrame)
        self.horizontalFrame_2 = MyFrame(Dialog)
        self.horizontalFrame_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(9, 41, 4, 255), stop:0.085 rgba(2, 79, 0, 255), stop:0.19 rgba(50, 147, 22, 255), stop:0.275 rgba(236, 191, 49, 255), stop:0.39 rgba(243, 61, 34, 255), stop:0.555 rgba(135, 81, 60, 255), stop:0.667 rgba(121, 75, 255, 255), stop:0.825 rgba(164, 255, 244, 255), stop:0.885 rgba(104, 222, 71, 255), stop:1 rgba(93, 128, 0, 255));")
        self.horizontalFrame_2.setObjectName("horizontalFrame_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalFrame_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalFrame_2)
        self.horizontalFrame_3 = MyFrame(Dialog)
        self.horizontalFrame_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:0, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), stop:0.05 rgba(14, 8, 73, 255), stop:0.36 rgba(28, 17, 145, 255), stop:0.6 rgba(126, 14, 81, 255), stop:0.75 rgba(234, 11, 11, 255), stop:0.79 rgba(244, 70, 5, 255), stop:0.86 rgba(255, 136, 0, 255), stop:0.935 rgba(239, 236, 55, 255));")
        self.horizontalFrame_3.setObjectName("horizontalFrame_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalFrame_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_8")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalFrame_3)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = MyQDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```